# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Exception Handling Not Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception, asp.net-mvc-4

When an error occurs in my ASP.NET MVC 4 application, I would like to customize a view for the user depending on the type of error.  For example, page not found or an exception has occurred (with some user-friendly details about the exception).  I've checked other examples of how to do this on StackOverflow and other online sources, but none of the answers are working for me.

The basic [HandleError] attribute does not seem to be working in VS2012 with an MVC 4 application targeting .NET 4.5.  Here is the code I have in my home controller:

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; //doesn't work with or without this
    throw new NullReferenceException("Uh oh, something broke.");
}
```

It is just throwing an exception, and I would expect the default ~/Shared/Error.cshtml view to be returned because of the [HandleError] attribute, but all I get is an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error indicating that the page could not be displayed.  I checked my web.config, and different configurations seem to be behaving weird.  In the  section, it currently contains:

```
<customErrors mode="On" />
```

(I've tried adding defaultRedirect and with customErrors mode="Off" as well but that didn't have any effect... neither the shared Error view or the CustomError view I have is being rendered.  If I change customErrors mode to off, then I can see the exception details as expected, so it is throwing the "Uh oh, something broke" exception properly.

I've also tried adding an OnException handler to the HomeController, and although I can debug through and see that the OnException event is being raised, it doesn't make any difference:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnException(filterContext);
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    if (filterContext == null)
    {
        filterContext.Result = View("CustomError");
        return;
    }
    Exception e = filterContext.Exception;
    // TODO: Log the exception here
    ViewData["Exception"] = e; // pass the exception to the view
    filterContext.Result = View("CustomError");
}
```

I have also tried changing [HandleError] to specify a view, but that doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
[HandleError(View="CustomError")]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.  Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seem to recall that you had to call the page from a non-localhost IP address (typically another computer). And it has to be an IIS based server, not the built-in development server (so IIS or IIS Express, but then you have to configure IIS Express for external access, which is a pain).

You can in fact debug it, you have to configure your local server on your debug computer to accept external requests, then call your local server from the remote server.

Comment: Even though I'm not using `RemoteOnly` anywhere in web.config, my original code does seem to work remotely, just not locally!  That is very surprising to me.  I did have to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` in the `<system.webserver>` section of web.config in order for the views to get rendered, but that seems normal. This makes it harder to debug locally, and seems like a bug since `mode=RemoteOnly` is not being used.  If anyone finds out how to get this to work locally, let me know.  (I may open a second question for that specifically.)

Answer (score 5):

I also went on a seamingly endless journey of reading SO answers and assorted blog postings trying to get custom error pages to work. Below is what finally worked for me.

The first step is to use IIS Express for debugging instead of the built-in Cassini web server to "guarantee" that the debug experience will mirror the live environment.

Create a controller to handle application errors and add an action for each custom error you will handle. The action should do any logging, set the status code, and return the view.

```
public class ErrorsController : Controller
{
    // 404
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult NotFound()
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        return View();
    }

    // I also have test actions so that I can verify it's working in production.
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Throw404()
    {
        throw new HttpException((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "demo");
    }
}
```

Configure the `customErrors` section in web.config to redirect to your custom error actions.

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Errors/InternalServerError">
      <error statusCode="400" redirect="Errors/BadRequest" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="Errors/Forbidden" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Errors/NotFound" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="Errors/InternalServerError" />
    </customErrors>
```

Add the `httpErrors` section to `system.webServer` and set the errorMode to Detailed in web.config. Why this works is a mystery to me, but this was the key.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

Add a catchall route last to the defined routes to direct 404s to the custom page.

```
            // catchall for 404s
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Error",
            "{*url}",
            new {controller = "Errors", action = "NotFound"});
```

You may also want to create a custom `HandleErrorAttribute` and register it as a global filter to log 500 errors.

These steps worked for me in both development (IIS Express) and production (IIS7) environments. You need to change `customErrors mode="On"` to see the effect in development.

Comment: I checked, and from Project Properties > Web, it was defaulted to "Use Local IIS Web Server" with IIS Express checked.  It will take me a bit to check the rest.

Comment: After removing my catch-all route for 404's, modifying the web.config, creating the ErrorsController, and hooking up the Errors/{Action} routes, it doesn't seem to work as expected.  It's as if the IIS server isn't redirecting to Errors/<path> properly when those status codes come up.  Navigating to <site>/Errors/<action>, works, but I don't get the custom page when I set `Response.StatusCode`.  If I remove the StatusCode, then I do get the custom page, but it doesn't trigger on other not found paths or exceptions (<site>/blah).  I've tested locally and remotely.

Comment: If the reason that the redirects aren't working may be found, then this approach could be viable (except that it may not be able to pass the actual exception to the InternalServerError view in order to render custom error pages, if that is needed).

Comment: An error needs to occur for custom error pages to work, setting Response.StatusCode won't trigger them (nor will returning HttpNotFoundResult() e.g.). The application needs to thrown an exception as shown in the Throw404 action in my ErrorsController. If you need to interpret the error and deliver a specific page, use a custom HandleErrorAttribute to catch 500s and redirect.

Comment: This doesn't really work. The final error url still sends a status code of 200 OK

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem and lost sometime trying to work out what was going on. So just in case any others face a similar problem here is what my problem was.

The error page was trying to use my _Layout page. Just ensure that you Error.cshtml page has

@{
  Layout = null;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following attribute to the `customErrors` tag:

```
defaultRedirect="Error"
```

This explicitly defines to which view MVC should redirect the user when the error is thrown and no view is specified by default in the attribute. This will of course only work if `Error.cshtml` exists in the `Shared` views folder.

Comment: I'm finally getting around to trying these suggestions.  It looks like using `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />` returned my PageNotFound error page instead of the content from the shared Error view and there was no exception data in ViewData.  I thought this was because /Error doesn't actually exist on the server and the web.config doesn't know anything about the actual views... but when I modified the OnException handler to use the "Error" view as well, that resulted in the same HTTP 500 error that I've been seeing all along, and I no longer see the PageNotFound page.  :(