# trying to set up grabbing all unhandled exceptions but it's not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a razor site that is working well but occasionally I get an unhandled exception. I am trying to track it down but for now I want to change it where they don't see this:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Test

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Here is what I have so far but it doesn't catch it.

Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{      
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
  routes.MapRoute("UnhandledExceptions", "Error", new { controller = "Error", action = "Index" });
  routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Account", action = "Logon", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

My ErrorController.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SuburbanCustPortal.Controllers
{
  public class ErrorController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
      return View("Error");
    }
  }
}
```

My test code to generate an error:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
  throw new Exception("Test");
}
```

I have this is in my web.config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error"/>
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error"/>
</customErrors>
```

What am I missing?

**====== EDIT #1 ======**

I made the change per Mike's answer and changed the web.config to:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
</customErrors>
```

I am getting this message:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: Test

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[Exception: Test]
   SuburbanCustPortal.Controllers.HomeController.Test() in D:\Suburban\s\Web Projects\WebPortal\SuburbanCustPortal\Controllers\HomeController.cs:133
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +264
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +129
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +826266
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +314
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +825488
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +335
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +54
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

This is the exception I get when I try to run the test above.

Comment: Are you trying to catch the exception, or redirect to a specific error page when you hit one. I'm guessing the later.

Comment: well... I'm trying to prevent any errors from going to the customer regardless of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your code says you are trying to do, what you want is this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/">
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I tried this and got the same results. No error captures but it displayed it in the webpage.

Comment: Sorry, not sure, this is exactly what I have on my site and it works without issue to solve the same thing you are trying to solve. Check out this other SO post, maybe there's something there for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13845318/asp-net-mvc-4-exception-handling-not-working

Answer (score 0):

To catch any unhandled exception, use the following construct in your global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
  public MvcApplication()
  {
    Error += MvcApplication_Error;
  }

  private void MvcApplication_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Exception exception = application.Server.GetLastError();
    ...process exception...

    // clear the exception from the server
    application.Server.ClearError();
  }
}
```